# Eclipse debug ignores breakpoints only with SpringBootTest webEnvironment

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have to the following test class:

```
package com.me.myservice.service;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MySpringApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyServiceServiceTest {
    
     @Autowired
     MyServiceService myServiceService;
  
   
     @Test
     public void myTest() {  
         Double value = myServiceService.execCalc();
         
         Assertions.assertEquals(0D, valor);
     }

}
```

When try to execute in Eclipse, using:

```
Debug As -> Maven test
```

or using:

```
Debug As -> Maven test -> Maven build...
GOAL: test
```

It runs my tests perfectly, with injection, database connection, all application context. But it ignores all my breakpoints.

Although, if I run the same application "normally", using:

```
Debug As -> Maven test -> Maven build...
GOAL: spring-boot:run clean
```

All my breakpoints will work.

Any clues how can I debug my tests in eclipse with all context application? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is Maven spawning another process to run your tests? If so, it's not connected to the debugger.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help!!! I don't think maven do that, because breakpoints work well with different goal. But I don't know how spring "SpringRunner" and "SpringBootTest" work internally... I have no idea if spring can spawn another process to run tests.